# How to code a scroll box onto an image?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, overlay

It's been several years since I dabbled in HTML and CSS; I'm very rusty.

I'm having a great deal of trouble getting a scroll box to sit properly on top of [this image](https://s5.postimg.org/pwy1ni4mv/Terminal_Screen.png).

What I would like to do is position a scroll box over the image so that the end result looks as though the text that will go into the scroll box appears to be scrolling on the terminal screen (and not over the gray frame housing the screen). Basically, I'd like the scroll box to go on top of the image, so that, when one scrolls through the content within the box, said content looks as though it's actually being scrolled on the terminal screen within the image (again, without the content scrolling over the screen's frame).

This is the coding that I managed to put together so far. It seems like it's a mess now... I hope it isn't so dishevelled that nobody can work with it.

```
<p style="background-image: url(https://s5.postimg.org/pwy1ni4mv/Terminal_Screen.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; margin:auto; width:1000px;height:591px;overflow:auto; position:relative; border:0px; padding-top: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 50px;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Content would go here...?<br target="_blank" rel="nofollow"/></p>
```

Comment: What do you mean with scroll box? Can you find an example online of what your trying to do? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see you have to you 2 divs: The first is for the background image and to hide the scrollbar, the second one is to contain the text and to make it scroll.  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrjy21hx/3/) here.

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="scroll">
      <a>
         ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
   .img{
  background-image: url(https://s5.postimg.org/pwy1ni4mv/Terminal_Screen.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 7%;
}

.scroll{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

.scroll a{
  font-size: 25px;
  color: green;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is absolutely lovely. Thank you so much. Due to the nature of the website that I'm trying to post this on, I have to ask: Is there any way to accomplish this using entirely HTML? Said website doesn't seem to like CSS very much...

Comment: the only way is to integrate the css code in the html markup in style attribute like this https://jsfiddle.net/hrjy21hx/4/

Comment: @AsterNyxx So you found your answer here.

Comment: Understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it like this?

```css
#screen {
  background-image: url("https://s5.postimg.org/pwy1ni4mv/Terminal_Screen.png"); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100% auto; 
  margin: auto; width: 1000px; 
  height: 591px; 
  position: relative; 
  border: 0px none; 
  padding: 50px 50px 0px;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
}

#container p {
  color: green; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  padding-left: 200px; 
  padding-right: 200px; 
  width: 630px; 
  height: 523px;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
  <div id="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<br target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
</p></div></div>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tLyoz8g/1/)

Comment: Yes! I'd like the content to cover the entire screen, including left to right, but that's pretty much what I'm going after!

Comment: I'm curious, though... If you don't mind showing me, what would the coding look like in entirely HTML?

Comment: @AsterNyxx You want the screen over the whole site?

Comment: The image of the terminal screen will actually only be on part of the web page (say, the center). I'd just like to figure out how to get a scroll box over it, as described, using HTML.

Comment: @AsterNyxx So you want to have inline `css`? Or do just want the text full width over the image? Your image is not transparent in the background, so if you get the content on the full width, it will get over the shadow.

Comment: I suppose I'm trying to figure out what exactly it is I need... The website (which I would rather not name, for privacy concerns) on which I am trying to get this to work is rather... odd... when it comes to HTML and CSS... I'm asking for HTML because, after trying many times, I've realized that CSS doesn't work very well on the aforementioned site. I suppose I'm okay with the content in the scroll box passing over the shadow on the terminal screen, as long as I can keep it off the screen's frame (the gray area outside the screen).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    document.getElementById("formPemasaranSertifikat").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("bodi").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .tv{
        background: url("https://s5.postimg.org/pwy1ni4mv/Terminal_Screen.png") no-repeat; 
        background-size: 100%;  
        width:1000px;
        height:591px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .textbox{
        width: 800px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 120px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        height: 470px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tv">
        <div class="textbox">
<p>Content would go here...?<br></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```